# Draw plotly bar traces under scatter traces rather than over?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to show several traces on the same plot in plotly/dash.  Regardless of the order of the traces I specify in the `data` variable, the bar traces always end up drawing over the scatter traces.  Here's what I've got for generating the plot.

Each of the scatter traces are generated with

```
go.Scatter(
    x=list(dfN['DATE'])
    ,y=list(dfN['VALUE'])
    ,text=list(dfN['VALUE'].round(decimals=3))
    ,hoverinfo='text+name'
    ,name='Scatter N'
    ,mode='lines+markers'
    ,marker=dict(
        color='rgb(230,159,0)',
        size=15,
        opacity=1,
        line={'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}
    )
)
```

and each of the bar traces are generated with

```
dropin_style=dict(
    hoverinfo='text+name'
    ,hoverlabel=dict(
        namelength=-1
    )
    ,textposition = 'auto'
    ,yaxis='y2'
)
go.Bar(
    legendgroup='bars'
    ,x=list(dfM['DATE'])
    ,y=list(dfM['VALUE'])
    ,text=list(dfM['VALUE'])
    ,name='Bar M'
    ,**dropin_style
    ,marker={'color':'#cccccc'}
    ,textfont=dict(color='#000000')
)
```

then the traces are all put together with

```
data = [bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4, bar5,
                scatter1, scatter2, scatter3,]
layout = go.Layout(
    showlegend=True
    ,legend=dict(orientation="h",x=0, y=1.3)
    ,barmode='stack'
    ,xaxis=dict(
        dtick='M1'
    )
    ,yaxis=dict(
        range=[0,1.1],
        fixedrange=True,
        title='Percent'
    )
    ,yaxis2=dict(
        range=[0, ymax]
        ,fixedrange=True
        ,side='right'
        ,title='Count'
        ,overlaying='y'
        ,zeroline=False
        ,showgrid=False
    )
)
return {'data': data, 'layout': layout}
```

What can I do in order to get the bar traces to plot under the scatter traces?  I tried setting opacity of the bars but it makes the whole graph way harder to look at.

Comment: Do you have the same issue when plotting offline, e.g. in a Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something's missing from your code here but I infer that `**dropin_style` specifies that the bars have `yaxis: "y2"` and from my trials it looks traces associated with `yaxis` get drawn, then those associated with `yaxis2` so if you want your scatter traces to be on top of your bar traces, you'll want the scatter traces associated with `yaxis2`, and you can switch up the `side` so that the correct ones end up on the right/left.

Comment: Whoops.  Just added the definition of dropin_style to my OP.  And that assumption is correct.  I'll switch the barchart to axis1 and see if that fixes it.

Comment: K, got the change made and that appears to be exactly the cause.  Shame that isn't documented somewhere but I guess it makes sense.  If the javascript library assembles the SVG in axis-order, then the `yaxis` would come before `yaxis2` and since SVG doesn't use z-index and just goes off of order, then `yaxis2` wouldn't be possible to put below `yaxis`.  Thanks!

Comment: Setting the `plot_bgcolor` to `rgba(0,0,0,0)` (transparent) also helped.